# Angular 2 service dependency injection fails (using angular-cli and $ng serve)

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-cli

I'm using a dependency injection in Angular 2 to inject a service to a component. Here's the code:

`./app/source-display/source-display.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CatalogService } from '../catalog.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-source-display',
  providers: [CatalogService],
  templateUrl: 'source-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['source-display.component.css']
})
export class SourceDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  active_source_id: number;
  sources: any;

  constructor(catalogService: CatalogService) {
      this.active_source_id = 1;
      this.sources = catalogService.getCatalog();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //   active_source_id = 0;
  }

}
```

`./app/catalog.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CatalogService {

  constructor() {}

  getCatalog() {
      return {
          0: {name: 'Source 0'},
          1: {name: 'Source 1'},
      }
  }

}
```

I'm also putting my `CatalogService` in the boostrap function in my main.ts file.

Here is the error message I get from running `ng serve` in the command line (from [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)):

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  C:/Users/arjun_000/github/slippy-astro-images/ng2-catdisplay/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-soAy8zVZ.tmp/0/src/app/source-display/source-display.component.spec.ts (10, 21): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
  C:/Users/arjun_000/github/slippy-astro-images/ng2-catdisplay/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-soAy8zVZ.tmp/0/src/app/source-display/source-display.component.ts (18, 12): Property '_catalogService' does not exist on type 'SourceDisplayComponent'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:120:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.Plugin (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:10:31)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.CachingWriter [as constructor] (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:21:10)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:27:5)
    at Angular2App._getTsTree (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:331:18)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:124:23)
    at new Angular2App (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:53:23)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\angular-cli-build.js:10:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:15:19)
    at C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\commands\serve.js:64:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\arjun_000\github\slippy-astro-images\ng2-catdisplay\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

I've noticed something strange: The code doesn't work as is, but if I comment out this section from the component --

```
  constructor(catalogService: CatalogService) {
      this.active_source_id = 1;
      this.sources = catalogService.getCatalog();
  }
```

-- and then run `ng serve` (which builds the app successfully), and then un-comment out the section, the app now refreshes works the way I want it to.

I'm not sure what I have to do to solve this. Any ideas? Is there a problem with my dependency injection itself or is there some other issue with just its use with this angular-cli command `ng serve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. **source-display.component.spec.ts** :

   Arguments in your this file are not valid, so i will suggest you to comment all the code in this file.
2. **source-display.component.ts**:

   You are injecting service in a wrong way, ideal syntax should be:

   ```
   constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService) {
      this.active_source_id = 1;
      this.sources = this.catalogService.getCatalog();
   }
   ```

declaring `constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService)` is equivalent to:

```
export class SourceDisplayComponent {
    private catalogService;

    constructor(catalogService: CatalogService) {
      this.catalogService=catalogService; //initialising instance variable with dynamically injected instance
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Commenting out `source-display.component.spec.ts` made it work for me! If I keep it commented out, am I really losing anything in terms of the app's functionality? Or are the .spec.ts files just for tests etc.?

And I've also fixed my constructor, thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Arjun `spec.ts` files are the configured test cases for angular-cli. if you get familiar with these test cases, then it will be easy for you to edit them. for development. You are not losing your apps functionality.